# How to setup imports in Eclipse for Java EE7

Tags: java, json, eclipse, import

I would like to follow this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp003.htm#BABHAHIA

and have downloaded the latest versions of eclipse EE and JDK (x32 for windows)

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html

And have created a java project, set the JRE to the jdk7 and changed the compiler compliance level to 1.7

but as soon as I try to use something like:

```
import javax.json.Json;
```

I encounter an error with it being unable to be resolved by eclipse - where can I configure eclipse such that it accepts these imports?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.json` is not part of the standard Java EE installation. You need to find the jar file and add it to your classpath.  The jar file can be found at https://java.net/projects/jsonp/downloads/directory/ri or if you're using Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I thought it was added in JEE 7, as described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp002.htm#BABDFHHD  
      
is there some way of doing a "full" install to get these things?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this exact issue. I am using JDK 7u67.  Eclipse does not recognize javax.json, even though Oracle (the previous link: docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp002.htm#BABDFHHD) indicates that these classes are part of 7.

I've been unable to find an answer. I did grab the .jar and put it in jre/lib/ext and eclipse was happy after a restart.

Comment: I suggest you ask your specific question as a new question, instead of as an answer to this one (it isn't an answer and thus does not belong here) - perhaps link to this one and explain how your setup is different.

Comment: I don't have a question.  I substantiated the OP's issue as well as the JRE7 documentation.  I also provided a work around that was suitable, if not the ideal solution.